# What is "oc_usd" Process on Cisco Nexus 7k and how to solve

Tags: cisco-nexus, cisco-nexus-7k

We have high CPU load on Cisco nexus 7K. The reason is "oc_usd" process.
Anyone knows anything about the process and how can we solve the issue?

Comment: That is the Octopus queuing module.

Answer (score 1):

The Octopus process relates to some internal ASICs. As for issue resolution, What changed? Could be a misconfiguration, software bug, bad hardware, etc. Use basic troubleshooting to narrow down possibilities. Opening a Cisco TAC case is a good initial step as well. Look at control plane policing as well as a possible fix.

Cisco's *Nexus 7000 High CPU Usage Troubleshooting Guide [Root Cause Analysis of High CPU Usage](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/interfaces-modules/nexus-7000-series-supervisor-1-module/116137-trouble-nexus7000-highcpu-00.html#anc20)* states:

> Symptoms of high CPU usage include control plane instability,
> data plane connectivity issues caused by control plane failure,
> protocol flapping such as Hot Standby Router Protocol (HSRP)/RP
> flapping, UDLD error disabling, Spanning Tree Protocol (STP) failure,
> and other connectivity issues.
>
> **`show processes cpu history` Command**
>
> If the switch was not reloaded or
> switched over, run the show processes cpu history command within 72
> hours of the outage in order to see if high CPU usage occurred at the
> time of the event.
>
> **CoPP and HWRL**
>
> If high CPU usage was the root cause of a past outage,
> and if you suspect that the outage was triggered by network traffic,
> you can use CoPP and HWRL (hardware rate limiter)  in order to help
> identify the type of traffic.